# RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout error using Firebase in Fragments

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I am new to Firebase and just used it today for our app. I have successfully inserted the items to my Firebase console. Now I want these items to display in my `Recyclerview` using Fragments.

I have experienced this error since morning and exhausted all the information but nothing seems to work for me.

Please check this code and enlighten me what seems to be the problem:

This my Category model

```
package com.example.devcash.Object;

public class Category {
    public String category_name;

    public Category(){

    }

    public Category(String category_name){
        this.category_name = category_name;
    }

    public String getCategory_name() {
        return category_name;
    }

    public void setCategory_name(String category_name) {
        this.category_name = category_name;
    }
}
```

CategoriesFragment

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_categories, container, false);

        //
        categoryrecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.catrecyclerview);
        categoryrecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        catlist = new ArrayList<Category>();

        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Category");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Category c = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Category.class);
                    catlist.add(c);
                }
                adapter = new CategoryAdapter(getContext(), catlist);
                categoryrecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Something is wrong, please try that again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
```

AddCategory

```
public class AddCategoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DatabaseReference firebaseDatabase;
    private FirebaseDatabase firebaseInstance;
    private String CategoryId;

    TextInputEditText categoryName;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_category);


        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        categoryName = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.text_categoryname);
        firebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        firebaseDatabase = firebaseInstance.getReference("DataDevcash");
        CategoryId = firebaseDatabase.push().getKey();

    }

    public void addCategory (String categoryName){
        Category category = new Category(categoryName);
        firebaseDatabase.child("Category").child(CategoryId).setValue(category);
    }

    public void insertCategory(){
        addCategory(categoryName.getText().toString().trim());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Category Successfully Added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == android.R.id.home){
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        }else if(id == R.id.action_save){ //if SAVE is clicked
            insertCategory();

        }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
}
```

CategoryAdapter

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Category> categoryArrayList;

    public CategoryAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Category> categories){
        context = c;
        categoryArrayList = categories;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.customlayout_category, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        viewHolder.categoryname.setText(categoryArrayList.get(i).getCategory_name());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return categoryArrayList.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView categoryname;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            categoryname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtcategory_name);
        }
    }
}
```

fragment_categories.xml

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/catrecyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/addcategories_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        android:tint="@color/whiteBG"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Logcat

```
RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

When I try to move my FirebaseDatabase code from `onCreateView` to `onCreate`, I will get this error from  my logcat.

Logcat

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.devcash.Fragments.CategoriesFragment.onCreate
```

I have also tried to change the `layout_height` from `match_parent` to `wrap_content` and vice versa but still the items will not show..

Comment: you should not be doing all of this in `onCreateView` but instead in something like `onViewCreated`

Comment: @a_local_nobody tried it and the data will still not show up :(

Answer (score 2):

The **first logcat** is simply a warning saying that **.setAdapter** has not been called on your recyclerView hence nothing would be loaded to it. This is probably because the overridden method **onDataChange** where you added **setAdapter** trigger was never called.

The **second logcat** is an error telling you that you tried to access the **RecyclerView** before it is initialized. Why? Because you are calling from the wrong method block. Check [android fragment lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating) for more info

To fix both issues refactor your code like below

-- Initialize your adapter and recyclerView only once. i.e inside onCreateView block

```
catlist = new ArrayList<Category>();
adapter = new CategoryAdapter(getActivity(), catlist);
categoryrecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

-- Call **notifyDataSetChanged** on the adapter anytime the value of catlist changes. Add the below code inside onDataChange callback method

```
    @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Category c = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Category.class);
                catlist.add(c);
            }
           adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
           // adapter = new CategoryAdapter(getContext(), catlist);
           // categoryrecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

You can verify if your implementation is right by adding some dummy data to catlist

```
 //call this any where and if it works then be rest assured 
 //that no data is returned from your firebase reference
 catlist.add(new Category("Sample Category"));
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I have tried this and still the data will not show up :(

Comment: Have you tried using the sample block with dummy data? catlist.add(new Category("Sample Category")); Add the block in onCreateView after setting the adapter to the recyclerView

Comment: I have tried it at it showed on my list. But when I remove it and add the actual item, it will not show

Comment: Confirm if onDataChanged is called by adding a toast or something

Comment: I don't think it's called at all because I have tried adding a toast message and won't show up

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
CategoryAdapter adapter = new CategoryAdapter(getContext());
categoryrecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new      
LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

categoryrecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter );

reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Category c = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Category.class);
                catlist.add(c);
            }
          adapter.pushData(catlist);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Something is wrong, please try that 
      again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

inside your adapter add this method

```
public void pushData(List<Category> list){
    this.list.clear();
    this.list.addAll(list);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am no longer seeing that error but still the data will not show in my `Recyclerview`  :(

Answer (score 0):

```html
CategoryAdapter adapter = new CategoryAdapter(getactivity(),catlist);
categoryrecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new      
LinearLayoutManager(getactivity()));

categoryrecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter );

reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        catlist.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Category c = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Category.class);
                catlist.add(c);
            }
          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Something is wrong, please try that 
      again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

change your adapter with attached array list.Get value from it.